# Is possible to exclude one marker from clustering?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2, markerclusterer

I use googleMaps v2 clustering

```
        mClusterManager = new ClusterManager<InfoMarker>(a.getBaseContext(), mMap);
        mInfoMarkerRenderer = new InfoMarkerRenderer(a, mMap, mClusterManager);
        mClusterManager.setRenderer(mInfoMarkerRenderer);
```

I have to exclude one marker from clustering, it is possible? 
I tried

```
mClusterManager.removeItem(item);
```

but no effects